# Drawing circle using Bing API does not work

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, bing-api

I am trying to draw a circle using the Bing Maps API. It centers the map onto the correct location but the circle and the associated tag/description do not show up.
It does not seem to be an API key issue. I am bloody new to this thing and don't know the error here. I simply store the code in a .HTML file and open it locally on my PC to test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bing Maps Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=MYKEY'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function loadMapScenario() {
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.7353, 7.1350),
                zoom: 12
            });
            
            // Create a circle with 1NM radius around the specified position
            var circle = new Microsoft.Maps.Circle(
                new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.7369, 7.1350),1852, // 1 nautical mile = 1852 meters
                { 
                    strokeColor: 'red', 
                    strokeThickness: 2, 
                    fillColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)' 
                });
            map.entities.push(circle);
            
            // Create a clickable tag with the specified text
            var infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(
                new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.7369, 7.1350), 
                { 
                    title: 'TEST_TITLE',
                    description: 'TEST_DESCRIPTION',
                    visible: true 
                });
            infobox.setMap(map);
            
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(circle, 'click', function () {
                infobox.setOptions({ visible: true });
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='loadMapScenario();'>
    <div id='myMap' style='width: 800px; height: 600px;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.Maps.Circle` is not a documented feature of the Bing Maps API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/)

To create a circle in Bing Maps you actually calculate the estimated points for a circle and pass it into a polygon. Here is a code snippet on how to do this:

```js
//Load the Spatial Math module.
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath', function () {
    var center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.7369, 7.1350);
    var radius = 1852; // 1 nautical mile = 1852 meters 

    //Calculate the locations for a regular polygon that has 36 locations which will rssult in an approximate circle. Radius units defaults to meters.
    var locs = Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.getRegularPolygon(center, radius, 36);
    
    //Create a polygon from the points.
    var circle = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(locs, { 
        strokeColor: 'red', 
        strokeThickness: 2, 
        fillColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)' 
    });
    map.entities.push(circle);
    
    //Add the rest of your code below.
    
});
```

It's also worth noting that Bing Maps supports multiple distance units, so no need to pre-convert your distance/radius. Here is a modified version of the code using nautical miles.

```js
//Load the Spatial Math module.
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath', function () {
    var center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.7369, 7.1350);
    var radius = 1, // 1 nautical mile = 1852 meters

    //Calculate the locations for a regular polygon that has 36 locations which will rssult in an approximate circle. You can set the distance units of the radius.
    var locs = Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.getRegularPolygon(center, radius, 36, Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.DistanceUnits.NauticalMiles);
    
    //Create a polygon from the points.
    var circle = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(locs, { 
        strokeColor: 'red', 
        strokeThickness: 2, 
        fillColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)' 
    });
    map.entities.push(circle);
    
    //Add the rest of your code below.
    
});
```

You can also find several samples of different ways to create/use circles in Bing Maps here: https://samples.bingmapsportal.com/?search=circle

**Update**

Here is a modified version of your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bing Maps Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=MYKEY'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function loadMapScenario() {
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.7353, 7.1350),
                zoom: 12
            });
            
            //Load the Spatial Math module.
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath', function () {
                var center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.7369, 7.1350);
                var radius = 1852, // 1 nautical mile = 1852 meters 

                //Calculate the locations for a regular polygon that has 36 locations which will rssult in an approximate circle. Radius units defaults to meters.
                var locs = Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.getRegularPolygon(center, radius, 36);
                
                //Create a polygon from the points.
                var circle = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(locs, { 
                    strokeColor: 'red', 
                    strokeThickness: 2, 
                    fillColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)' 
                });
                map.entities.push(circle);

            
                // Create a clickable tag with the specified text
                var infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(
                    new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.7369, 7.1350), 
                    { 
                        title: 'TEST_TITLE',
                        description: 'TEST_DESCRIPTION',
                        visible: true 
                    });
                infobox.setMap(map);
                
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(circle, 'click', function () {
                    infobox.setOptions({ visible: true });
                });         
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='loadMapScenario();'>
    <div id='myMap' style='width: 800px; height: 600px;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which part of my code has to be replaced with yours? I am bloody new to this.

Comment: The circle code. I've updated my response to show you.

Comment: Still not loading anything. Is it possible that in your code, the closing bracket for "locs"  is missing:

`var circle = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(locs, { `

But even when i add this closing bracket, it still shows nothing on the map.

Comment: Old, not even sure why that location call is there. It isn't in the copy of the code I have on my computer. I've updated the code.

Comment: Still a completely blank page when using the code. When I omit the whole Math part, it at least displays the map. Theres a typo in the code but I cannot find what's wrong.

Comment: Found a typo. Had a comma instead of a semi-colon beside the radius variable. I corrected the sorce code above. Also, be sure to add your Bing Maps key to the script tag.